# Sum of Subspaces on $\mathbb{F^{4}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

In *Linear Algebra Done right* Axler asks us to verify the following theorem the following is my attempt is it correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $U_1=\{(x,x,y,y)\in\mathbf{F^{4}}|x,y\in\mathbf{F}\}$ and $U_2=\{(x,x,x,y)\in\mathbf{F^{4}}|x,y\in\mathbf{F}\}$ are subspaces of $\mathbf{F^{4}}$ Then
$$U_1+U_2=W=\{(x,x,y,z)\in\mathbf{F^{4}}|x,y,z\in\mathbf{F}\}$$
**Proof.** Consider an arbitrary $u\in U_1+U_2$ evidently $u=u_1+u_2$ for some $u_1\in U_1$ and $u_2\in U_2$ where $u_1=(x_1,x_1,y_1,y_1)$ and $u_2=(x_2,x_2,x_2,y_2)$ then $u=(x_1+x_2,x_1+x_2,y_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)\in W$. We may now conclude that $U_1+U_2\subseteq W$.

Consider now an arbitrary $w\in W$ where $w=(x,x,y,z)$, now consider the vectors $u_1=(\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{2},y-\frac{x}{2},y-\frac{x}{2})\in U_1$ and $u_2=(\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{2},z-y-\frac{x}{2})\in U_2$.
$u_1+u_2=(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2},y-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2},z+y+\frac{x}{2}-y-\frac{x}{2})=(x,x,y,z)=w$ consequently $w\in U_1+U_2$. Since $w$ was arbitrary it follows that $W\subseteq U_1+U_2$.

Taking the above two results together we may now conclude that $U_1+U_2=W$.

$\blacksquare$

*NOTE:* Here $\mathbf{F^{4}}$ can be either $\mathbf{R^{4}}$ or $\mathbf{C^{4}}$.

Comment: Looks correct  !

Comment: As for your note, your base field $\mathbb{F}^4$ can be any field of characteristic not $2$!